# Malloc error in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, heap-memory

I am doing a project for class and I believe I have the framework correct. Well besides the fact that it doesn't work. Usually with syntax or logic errors, I can pinpoint a location where I messed up, but this time I am completely lost and I have no idea how to fix this. Here is the what it throws out at me:

```
DELETE
DELETE
heapOfStudents(642,0x7fff74944300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd2d2803208: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Yea I have no idea what I did. But I seemed to activate a trap card or something. Anyways you all probably need to see my code so here it is.

```
//main.cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "student.h"
#include "address.h"
#include "date.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Student *S = new Student[50];

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("data.dat");

    string lines[51];
    string item;
    int x = 0;
    while(!inFile.eof()){
        getline(inFile, item);
        if(item != ""){
            lines[x] = item;
            x++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++){
        string line = lines[i];
        string delimiter = ",";

        size_t pos = 0;
        string sub;
        x = 0;

        while((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != string::npos){
            sub = line.substr(0, pos);
            line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            if(x == 0){
                S[i].setLName(sub);
            }else if(x == 1){
                S[i].setFName(sub);
            }else if(x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 || x == 6){
                S[i].setAddressInfo(sub, x - 2);
            }else if(x == 7 || x == 8){
                S[i].setDate(sub, x - 7);
            }else if(x == 9){
                S[i].setGPA(sub);
            }else{
                S[i].setCredHours(line);
            }
            x++;

            delete S;
        }

    }

    inFile.close();

    return 0;

}
```

And here is the Student.cpp

```
//student.cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

Student::Student(){

}

void Student::setFName(string fName){
    Student::fName = fName;
}

void Student::setLName(string lName){
    Student::lName = lName;
}

void Student::setGPA(string GPA){
    Student::GPA = GPA;
}

void Student::setCredHours(string credHours){
    Student::credHours = credHours;
}

void Student::setAddressInfo(string info, int part){
    if(part == 0){
        Student::home.setAddress1(info);
    }else if(part == 1){
        Student::home.setAddress2(info);
    }else if(part == 2){
        Student::home.setCity(info);
    }else if(part == 3){
        Student::home.setState(info);
    }else if(part == 4){
        Student::home.setZip(info);
    }
}

void Student::setDate(string info, int part){
    if(part == 0){
        Student::dateOfBirth.setDate(info);
    }else if(part == 2){
        Student::dateOfComp.setDate(info);
    }
}

string Student::getFName(){
    return Student::fName;
}

string Student::getLName(){
    return Student::lName;
}

string Student::getGPA(){
    return Student::GPA;
}

string Student::getCredHours(){
    return Student::credHours;
}

void Student::reportStudent(){

}

void Student::unsortedPrint(){

}

Student::~Student(){
    cout << "DELETE" << endl;
}
```

If you need to see my other two files just holla at me. Any help would be great cause I am just stuck on this roadblock.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `delete S` frees your array of 50 `Student`s, and you do it repeatedly.

Comment: Additionally, use `delete[] S` to delete an array. If you don't, there's no guarantee that the `Student` destructors will be called on every element of the array when you delete it.

Comment: Why do you limit your program to 50 students for no reason? It's actually easier to allow any number of students by using `std::vector`. `while(!inFile.eof())` is wrong. It should be `while (getline(inFile, item))`

Comment: @NeilKirk, it's not uncommon for class projects to require manual allocations for learning purposes.

Comment: @zneak I know, it's something I strongly disagree with. Would soldiers learn how to fight with swords before guns?

Comment: Pass strings by const reference. `this->fName = fName;` is more robust, as it still works if you change the name of the class.

Comment: The `while(!inFile.eof()){` (besides using the wrong loop condition) also needs to stop if `x` reaches `50`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only do you never store information in the dynamic array `S`, but you seem to `delete S` but it never had any stored data.

Also, you must use `delete[] S` unless you only want to deallocate the contents of the first memory address.

Comment: It's allocated in the first line of code in `main`.

Comment: Don't say consider when actually it's a must!

Comment: @DonLarynx Thanks man. I have no idea what I was thinking when I did that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code. First, you allocate an array (`S = new Student[50]`), but deallocate it as it was not an array (`delete S` instead of `delete[] S`). If you allocate something with `new[]`, you must delete it with `delete[]`.

Secondly, you `delete` in a loop. If you allocate something once, you should only delete it once. Move `delete S` two rows below, right before `inFile.close()`, and replace it with `delete[] S`, and it should work just fine.

EDIT: another issue in your code, that is not related to the error you see, is that you allocate 50 elements (`= new Student[50]`), but access 51 (`i < 51`). Either allocate 51 element, or change you loop to only make 50 iterations.

Comment: @isameal Thanks man. I had a brain fart with that i  < 51 thing. I appreciate the help.